# Search filter in listview error in position when click

Tags: android, listview

Hi everyone I am developing an app on importing/exporting and updating csv where I have this edittext filter.

The id of the seached item becomes 1 when I select it.

Below is my code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {


                TextView cat;
                TextView code;
                TextView desc;
                TextView unit;
                TextView quan;



                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                cat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproductcompany);
                String gory = cat.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, gory);

                code = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproductname);
                String deco = code.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA2, deco);

                desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproductprice);
                String csed = desc.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA3, csed);

                unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtunit);
                String noti = unit.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA4, noti);

                quan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtquan);
                String quanti = quan.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA5, quanti);

                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA1 , String.valueOf(id + 1));
                startActivity(intent);


                lv.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                lv.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);


            }

        });
```

Code for filtering items on Search:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text

                ((SimpleAdapter)MainActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The id which your using is The row id of the item that was clicked. When you search something if you find one record which is matching then id will be 0 your adding 1 to it so your getting 1

Comment: so what should i do sir i did that because of my code in insert data im now confused please help me sir @user6380043

Comment: Why don't you try to pick it's position from list and set it as a id

Comment: ok sir ill try to google on how because i used that string.value of(id) in update query maybe im wrong :(